# Can recently released US student vacation in Switzerland?

Tags: united-states, international-law, switzerland

[Iran recently released an American student that was being imprisoned in Tehran](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/12/07/us/politics/iran-prisoner-swap-xiyue-wang.html?). He was flown to Switzerland to meet with a US State Dept official.

My question: since he's already in Switzerland, would he be able to take advantage of the trip and ask for a few days' vacation in Zurich after he finishes all the paperwork? Or is this US government *by the book* stuff?

Comment: This would be better asked on [Expatriates.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Machavity questions about vacations and other short-term travel generally belong on [Travel.SE].  This question could also work on [Law.SE], depending on the focus.  I don't see anything to suggest that it's on topic for [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf: whom would he ask for vacation?  Are you asking whether the Swiss authorities will allow him to remain in Switzerland or something else?  If the former, US citizens can generally stay in the Schengen area for up to 90 days in any 180-day period, so if he was admitted under normal conditions he doesn't need to ask.

Comment: @phoog I'm not sure this applies to Travel, though (he didn't willingly go there). EP.SE tends to focus more on citizenship questions, and since he was there at the behest of the US gov, it still seems to apply. Either way, it's off-topic here

Comment: @Machavity I agree that it's questionable for [Travel.SE], but it's less questionable there than at [Expatriates.SE], where questions about citizenship arise because expatriates often seek naturalization, but that has nothing to do with this question.  (Also, Travel does not exclude questions about unwilling travel.).  Since hypothetical questions are quite normal at [Law.SE], that might indeed be the best place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they likely wouldn't be able to. The biggest problem is lack of a valid passport or other identification. Personal health and finances would also be a concern after 3 years in prison as a spy. All the paperwork is likely a fairly lengthy debreifment process, that involves talking to people in the United States, so a ride back may be part of the process.

It's also possible that he actually was a spy in which case vacation isn't likely. We know countries spy on each other fairly regularly, and catch spies from other nations as well. Whether they are a spy or not a country is always going to deny that officially. Prisoner swaps like the one that happened here are common ways to exchange captured spies. If he really was a spy then he is likely going to be quietly reassigned somewhere inside the United States and foreign travel would be difficult or impossible without a different identity, as no country is going to let in a potential spy.

Comment: "Yeah, I was at the center of a major diplomatic kerfuffle.... but look at the *powder* on the slopes......"

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that he lacks a valid passport?  How did he get into Switzerland without one?  Even if he did, he can get a new passport from the US embassy in Switzerland.

Comment: It makes sense that he would need to debriefed in the US after filling out all the necessary paperwork in Switzerland.

Comment: @phoog - maybe the assumption is (a) taken when imprisoned, (b) expired in prison, and (c) lacking appropriate visas, which is almost certain.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet US citizens do not need visas to enter Switzerland for visits of less than 90 days in any 180-day period, so it's quite possible that the person in question does not suffer from the lack of a necessary visa.  Besides, if the purpose of his trip requires him to have a visa, the Swiss surely issued it.  Otherwise, they wouldn't have admitted him.  Similarly, if he emerged from prison without a valid passport, the US Department of State will have provided one, or some substitute acceptable to the Swiss authorities.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I'm still not clear about what the question is asking.  Is the question is whether the US would let him stay in Switzerland, or whether Switzerland will let him stay in Switzerland?

Comment: @phoog - I think it's just a general would there be an obstacle from either if that person were to say "hey, before we ship me back, can I take a few days?"  Since it's the US's travel dime, I'd guess there isn't flexibility.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet in fact, it appears that he's getting a few days ("several," actually) in Germany: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/dec/07/us-citizen-to-be-released-from-iranian-jail-in-prisoner-swap

Comment: @phoog - Huh. So his "medical examinations" are going to take several days longer than the other person's? That does sound a bit like maybe he was an actual spy (debriefing), were I the type to wear a tinfoil hat....